# Trying to mimic MS Paint in C#, can't get rubber banding to work

Tags: c#, bitmap, draw, paint

I'm attempting mimic the effect in MS Paint where when drawing a shape, it is "previewed" on screen while the mouse is down.

Very simply:

```
    private Bitmap lastCanvas;                

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         lastCanvas = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.image);

         gr = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);

         start = e.Location;
         gr.DrawRectangle(myPen, start.X, start.Y, 0, 0);
         pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {   
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = lastCanvas;

            gr = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);

            gr.DrawRectangle(myPen, start.X, start.Y, e.Location.X - start.X, e.Location.Y - start.Y);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

The problem is it doesn't seem to be storing "lastCanvas" properly. It's an attempt to take everything drawn so far and store it, so that while the mouse drag is happening, I can redraw it before the rectangle "preview" is drawn. For some reason I can't get the bitmap to copy and redisplay, I just get all of my "preview" rectangles building up on screen despite the fact that I'm saving the old canvas and restoring it between every mouse move.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `lastCanvas`? A property? Can you post the relevant code where that is declared?

Comment: lastCanvas is just a Bitmap object, I'll add it to the first post, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe is happening is that `pictureBox1` and `lastCanvas` are referencing the same thing in your `pictureBox1_MouseMove` event handler.

This code sets the image and lastCanvas to the same object in memory

```
pictureBox1.Image = lastCanvas;
```

When you draw your image to the `Graphics` object you create, you're also updating lastCanvas.  You might have to `Clone` the bitmap.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that! Works perfectly now, thank you very much for pointing that out!